Error when using Torchaudio library to create a data set
I am following a YT course to work on the urban 8k data set which uses Torchaudio. The author wrote the exact same code but was able to get an output while I get this error:

RuntimeError: Couldn't find appropriate backend to handle uri C:\Users\hbhavnag\Documents\Hussain\ASU\collision detection\urban sounds\UrbanSound8K\audio\5\100263-2-0-121.wav and format None.

Following is my code:
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import pandas as pd
import torchaudio
import os

class UrbanSoundDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self,annotation_file,audio_dir):
        self.annotations = pd.read_csv(annotation_file)
        self.audio_dir = audio_dir

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.annotations)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        audio_sample_path = self._get_audio_sample_path(index)
        label = self._get_audio_sample_label(index)
        signal, sr = torchaudio.load(audio_sample_path)
        return signal, label
    
    def _get_audio_sample_path(self,index):
        fold = f"fold{self.annotations.iloc[index,5]}"
        path = os.path.join(self.audio_dir, fold, self.annotations.iloc[index,0])
        return path
    
    def _get_audio_sample_label(self, index):
        return self.annotations.iloc[index,6]
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        annotations_file = r"C:\Users\hbhavnag\Documents\Hussain\ASU\collision detection\urban sounds\UrbanSound8K\metadata\UrbanSound8K.csv"
        audio_dir = r"C:\Users\hbhavnag\Documents\Hussain\ASU\collision detection\urban sounds\UrbanSound8K\audio"
        usd = UrbanSoundDataset(annotations_file, audio_dir)
        print (f"There are {len(usd)} samples in the dataset")

    signal, label = usd[2]

I tried looking up the documentation for Torchaudio but was not sure if anything directly there was able to help me. I am assuming there are some version compatibility issues.
I am using Windows.
